# Using System.Reactive with events

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, system.reactive

I am developing a WPF application. User can change their Address in a form. I want to raise an event when user clicks a button (to change their address) and use the `UserInfoEventArgs` to process some information. I am trying to use Reactive Extensions.

[MS Documentation (`Subject<T>` constructor)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211737(v=vs.103))

I have two doubts. How to subscribe to `mySubject` and also how to add the `UserInfoEventArgs` to the subject.

```
Subject<string[]> mySubject = new Subject<string[]>();

// How to subscribe to mySubject and use the method "AddressSubscriber" as the subscriber?

private void UserDataChangedHandler (object sender, UserInfoEventArgs info)
{
    string[] updatedAddress = info.NewAddress.ToArray();  

    if (updatedAddress.Any())
    {
        // How to add "updatedAddress" to mySubject so that "AddressSubscriber" can use it?
    }
}

private void AddressSubscriber(string[] adrs)
{ 
    // Do some operations with adrs
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Observable.FromEventPattern` method instead of creating a superfluous `Subject<T>`:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<RoutedEventHandler, RoutedEventArgs>(
    h => btn.Click += h,
    h => btn.Click -= h)
        .Select(_ => new UserInfoEventArgs())
        .Subscribe(args => { /* do something with the args...*/ });
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to subscribe to `mySubject` and use the method `AddressSubscriber` as the subscriber?

```
mySubject.Subscribe(adrs => AddressSubscriber(adrs));
```

> How to add `updatedAddress` to `mySubject` so that `AddressSubscriber` can use it?

```
mySubject.OnNext(updatedAddress);
```